# Terraform data block only if it is dev env

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to get the list of users in an IAM group. The group only exists in dev account and not prod

```
# lookup for user accounts in Developers group only if its dev env
data "aws_iam_group" "developers" {
  count  = var.profile == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  group_name = "Developers"
}
```

When I have the below

```
locals = {
    mapdevelopers  =  [
      for index, x in data.aws_iam_group.developers[count.index].users : {
        username = x.user_name
        userarn  = x.arn
        groups   = ["system:masters"]
      }
    ] 
}
```

I am getting error

```
│ The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data"
│ blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

╵

so, I tried my locals without count.index like

```
locals = {
    mapdevelopers  =  [
      for index, x in data.aws_iam_group.developers.users : {
        username = x.user_name
        userarn  = x.arn
        groups   = ["system:masters"]
      }
    ] 
  }
```

Now I am getting an error

```
│ Because data.aws_iam_group.developers has "count" set, its attributes must
│ be accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     data.aws_iam_group.developers[count.index]
```

How can I obtain `mapdevelopers` local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `count` for `aws_iam_group`, this will transform this resource into an array of resources. If you want to iterate over it and access certain item, you would want to use the [`splat`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat). Moreover, in your case you need to `flatten` the `users` property to get the correct values:

```
locals {
  mapdevelopers = [
    for index, x in flatten(data.aws_iam_group.developers[*].users) : {
      username = x.user_name
      userarn  = x.arn
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Output will be something like:

```
mapdevelopers = [
  {
    "groups" = [
      "system:masters",
    ]
    "userarn" = "arn:aws:iam::069700690111:user/random-user"
    "username" = "random-username"
  },
]
```

This will work even if `count  = var.profile == "dev" ? 1 : 0` evaluates to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just update this `data.aws_iam_group.developers[count.index].users` to this `data.aws_iam_group.developers[0].users`

Comment: it worked for dev, but getting an error in prod `data.aws_iam_group.developers is empty tuple`.
How can I make the variable `mapdevelopers ` only for dev?

Comment: You can do `for index, x in try(data.aws_iam_group.developers[0].users, null)`

Comment: got similar error `Error: Iteration over null value.data.aws_iam_group.developers is empty tuple`